# examples of use of permanents

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, counting-complexity, permanent

It is known that if calculating permanent is easy, then solving hard problems in NP is easy. Is there a transparent example regarding application of say finding independent set or find chromatic number of a graph through the permanent?

Comment: Since you can reduce #3SAt to the permanent, you can solve the permanent to find the number of solutions to the 3SAt instance. if it's more than zero, the problem is satisfiable.

Comment: @SureshVenkat that is true. I was thinking of something else.. along the lines of given a graph using a single calculation of permanent to find the max indep number. Was curious if such a trick existed!

Comment: If you want a really transparent example, the permanent of the [biadjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Adjacency_matrix_of_a_bipartite_graph) of a bipartite graph counts the number of perfect matchings in this graph. For a non-bipartite graph, the permanent of its adjacency matrix counts the number of cycle covers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hint for your question in the comment to the question.  The independence number of a graph can be computed by a polynomial-time oracle Turing machine which calls the #P oracle just once.  That is, the independence number is in class FP<sup>#P[1]</sup>.

For a graph *G* on *n* vertices, let *g*<sub>*k*</sub>(*G*) be the number of independent sets of size *k* in *G*.  Note that 0≤*g*<sub>*k*</sub>(*G*)<2<sup>*n*</sup>.  Let

$$f(G)=\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{nk}g_k(G).$$

I leave the rest of the proof as exercise.

1. Show that function *f* is in #P.
2. Show that the independence number of *G* can be computed from two integers *n* and *f*(*G*) in time polynomial in *n*, and conclude that the independence number can be computed in FP<sup>#P[1]</sup>.
3. (If this is not clear from item 2,) conclude that the independence number can be computed by a polynomial-time oracle Turing machine which calls the oracle for the permanent just once.

The same idea works also for the chromatic number.

Comment: I think this is what I may be looking for. I am unfamiliar with #P proofs. There has to be a way to show $1$ can be found through permanent of an appropriately constructed matrix. That matrix and its construction is probably what I am seeking?

Comment: @vs: As I suggested in this answer, you should forget about the permanent and just use the definition of #P until step 3.  Once you have a proof, you can rewrite the whole proof to use the permanent throughout the proof, but that is not intuitive because the proof of the #P-completeness of the permanent is unintuitive.